# Ошибка Ajax при передаче через http://

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Есть форма ввода данных, где нужно ввести `URL`, чтобы что-то произошло. Данные формы отправляются через `Ajax-POST` на обработчик `PHP`. Сам обработчик при переходе на него ошибки не выдает.
Вот сам код `Ajax`:

```
function call() {
  var msg = $('#send').serialize();
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: '/oauth/v1/logup',
      data: msg,
      success: function(data) {
        $('#_data').html(data);
      },
      error:  function(xhr, str){
    alert('Возникла ошибка: ' + xhr.responseCode);
      }
    });

}
```

Когда отправляю запрос с формы, например ввёл значение `site.ru`, то адрес успешно передаётся на обработчик, а вот если `http://site.ru`, то возникает ошибка `undefined`. В чём может быть проблема?

Comment: библиотека jQuery нe загружена в страницу

Comment: @Igor подключена. Если в форму ввести просто site.ru, то всё отправляется, а вот с `http://site.ru` уже ошибка

Comment: приведите полный текст ошибки

Comment: @Igor undefined. Такая ошибка.

Comment: `console.log(xhr);` - ?

Comment: @Igor POST /oauth/v1/logup 403 ()

Comment: @Igor такая ошибка в консоли

Comment: @Igor можете сами посмотреть https://vkgod.win/oauth/token